# Streaming Desktop over Diffrent Platforms for Speed

Tags: c, bitmap, cross-platform, screen-capture

I needed to create a small remote desktop software in 'C' that compiles on various platforms (linux, freebsd, windows...) i've been looking into various image formats for a while, but still couldn't come up with a good idea to use them, right now, here is what i do:

```
1. Convert All Formats into Windows Bitmap (XImage,...etc)
2. Do a byte-to-byte comparion and replace the identical bytes with zeros
3. Preform a RLE (Run Length Encoding) on the Resulted data.
4. Transmit the Packet to the Server
5. Inverse the Operation on the Server by Reconstructing the Image through the previous image (Comparing Last Image with the New one Discarding Zero Bytes after RLE)
```

but this tends to be very slow, since the bitmap image format has very big files already because it contains no compression, and on platforms such as Mac OS X, the bitmap size is rediculously big because of the very hight resolution.

is there any faster and better way to do desktop streaming?

Comment: Why not use VNC which is open source?

Comment: no homework, im coding as a hoppy

Answer (score 2):

There are things you can take into account with computer screens, mainly that only small portions of the screen are likley to change at any one time.

You could look these three approaches:

1. Break the screen up into rectangles, for each screen update only transmit those that have changed along with thier location.
2. Use a compressed image format, like png or jpeg, or compress the bitmaps using [**zlib**](http://zlib.net/) rather than RLE.
3. Reduce the colour depth of your images when you capture them, reducing the images to 4bit or 8bit colour will vastly reduce the amount of data you send and the amount of data you have to compare for changes.

Depending on how you want to write the server, you may be able to take hints from the OS as to which bits of the screen have changed to reduce the amount of processing you have to do.

Lastly, (if this is not homework) then look at things like [**VNC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) that already do this pretty well, there are even java or c# versions.

Comment: as far as i know, 1) and 2) can't be done at the same time, but i will test the performance of each of them, but for 1) i got no idea how to do that actually, is this the same as splitting the File to like 4 parts for example?

Comment: Break the screen up into sections, and encode each as a separate png/jpeg